# Cant install mailspring

Tags: mail

Theres a dependency error when i try to install mailspring it was like this:

```
usr@user-HP-EliteBook-8470p:~$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/mailspring-1.8.0-amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mailspring.
(Reading database ... 221480 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mailspring-1.8.0-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mailspring (1.8.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailspring:
 mailspring depends on libsecret-1-dev; however:
  Package libsecret-1-dev is not installed.
 mailspring depends on gconf2; however:
  Package gconf2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mailspring (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mailspring
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt install -f` and you'll get the missing depenencies.